# Xmlpdf - how to obtain white (or invisible) selectable text

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xslt

I am writing a java program that uses an xmlpdf library.
The customer wants a selectable but invisible text on the pdf printout. I though of using a white font but whatever tags and attributes I try in the template, the text appears in black (same for all non-black colours, not just white).

For instance, this shows black, not blue:

```
            <text x="1" y="1" fill="blue" stroke="blue"
                  font-size="6pt" font-style="italic"
                  style="font-family:arial;stroke-width:0.5">
                Ibex
            </text>
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Actually I tried color="white" with no success. Both "white" and "#00FF00" have the same effect - the text remains black.

Comment: On the other hand, fill-color="#00FF00" works - the text background is green. The fill-color="white" works as expected, too. It seems like I cannot control only the font colour.

Comment: I found this in the logs of the pdf printer: **warning:350 Found unknown attribute [color]**.

Comment: Its's a legacy software, so all is quite dated: xmlpdf-3.9.1, java 1.6, Windows desktop application. I've contacted their support and they say that the library is not supported anymore. They still maintain a webpage, but the java library is impossible to download now. The library is widely used in the application, it would be a hard task to get rid of it. I described the situation to the support guy and wait...

Comment: Thanks for motivating me not to give up ;-). The hints you gave me didn't work, but using jad and the debugger I did some reverse engineering. Using a breakpoint in the logger I found out the list of all possible attributes and found the one that sets the text colour. It is called **text-color**. What a surprise! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jad and the debugger I did some reverse engineering. With a breakpoint set in the Logger.warn that produced "warning:350 Found unknown attribute [color]", I got the list of all possible attributes and found the one that sets the text colour.

It is called **text-color**. What a surprise! ;-)